# Image added to Cocoa and Cocoa Touch tags

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Company logos on tag wikis; are they allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/company-logos-on-tag-wikis-are-they-allowed)

Certain tags have images, however it seems like one the most major tags is missing. Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch should both have little images. Perhaps this one from Apple: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/technologies/mac/images/cocoa_cup.jpg

Now, I am not sure about licenses on that, but you get the idea.

Opinions, thoughts. I would like to hear them.

Comment: No, [they shouldn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/company-logos-on-tag-wikis-are-they-allowed). I occasionally go through tags and mass remove logos which have slipped through the cracks into tag wikis.

Answer (score 6):

The images that appear on tags themselves (for example, [on the android tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRvgv.png)) are there because [the tags have been sponsored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) by whatever companies own or represent the concepts behind those tags.

If Apple wants to sponsor the [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) and [cocoa-touch](/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) tags, they'll get little icons too. :)

Far as images in tag wikis go, [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) covered it well in comments: [images should not be included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/company-logos-on-tag-wikis-are-they-allowed).

Comment: Alright, thanks. That makes sense.